# Is it possible to let the iPhone system time run faster for a moment?

Tags: iphone

Maybe this can solve out the ugly delay with touchesBegan: to touchesMoved:. It is caused artifically by iPhone OS to check if the user really wants to move. In some situations the finger must be tracked without delay, otherwise it just looks ugly. You see that everywhere through iPhone OS. Sliders, Scroll Views.

Maybe accelerating the system time makes the delay smaller.

Comment: I tried making the layer speed bigger. Didn't help at all.

Comment: This is off topic, but the title of this question made me think of "FAST" mode on the Sinclair ZX81...

Answer (score 2):

You can set [UIScrollView:delaysContentTouches](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) to be NO, which will solve this.

You really don't want to change the system time to hack out something like this.  Do you want apps you're using to screw up your calendar and alarms and your phone log, etc?

Comment: You're right, that could screw up other things. I really think it sucks apple did not think much about the ugly appearance that can be caused by this kind of delays. A simple way to deactivate any waiting would have been fine. Unfortunately, setting delaysContentTouches to NO will still cause a small delay. It still waits to determine if you really want to scroll. That's stupid. I measured it in a blank new project. About 0.15 sec., which is just enough to let a tactile app look like it has programming errors.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122616/when-does-a-touchesbegan-become-a-touchesmoved), still open.

I don't think there's a way around it for now, seeing as even the ultra lickable "slide to unlock" slider suffers from the problem.

At this point I think the only solution is try smoothing this initial bump out with a bit of position interpolation.