# Delay Between 'tochesBegan' and 'touchesMoved'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm working with hand drawing parts of my app.

When I'm trying to draw very very tiny line(like 2~3 pixels)
it remains just ONE pixel.
And move my thouch further then jump to 4 pixels. :(

It's not a performance issue.
There is delay between 'tochesBegan' and 'touchesMoved' event.

I think it's related with this :
[When does a touchesBegan become a touchesMoved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122616/when-does-a-touchesbegan-become-a-touchesmoved)

The strange thing is it's not happening on iOS Simulator
And SketchBookX(A popular drawing app)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: The question is 'How can i remove that delay between tochesBegan and tochesMoved'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh FINALLY I found my fault!

[image]

If touch moves very short after 'touchesBegan', doesn't fire 'touchesMoved'.

But when 'touchesEnd' it gives moved point X(

It's little odd but finally i've done with it :)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to remove the delay if there is one? Simply deal with it and draw a line between the last point you received and the new point. 4 pixels or 2 to 3 pixels aren't even visible by the user - their finger alone will cover a 45 pixel radius so as they drag their finger to draw 2 / 3 / 4 won't be noticeable and it shouldn't matter anyway if you're connecting dots

Comment: It's QUITE noticeable. Try GLPaint sample code [HERE](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328). Long line? It's OK with interpolation. But try very short line? It fires only 'touchesBegan'. That means only ONE point. Can't interpolate :(

Comment: Clearly it's not a problem but an implementation issue, can't see why I was down voted